# grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sda fails (Funtoo)

Tags: grub2, boot-loader, chroot, gpt, funtoo

I am trying out [Funtoo](http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Welcome) on a new machine. I've been through the installation process, as described in [Funtoo Linux Installation](http://www.funtoo.org/Funtoo_Linux_Installation) . Specifically, the installation is done from within an existing Linux distro via [chroot](http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Funtoo_Linux_Installation#Chroot_into_Funtoo), though in a new empty SSD. All went fine up to the point of [installing the bootloader](http://www.funtoo.org/Funtoo_Linux_Installation#Installing_a_Bootloader) which fails:

```
grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sda
source_dir doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory
```

The partitions created are:

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1026047   500.0 MiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   2         1026048         1091583   32.0 MiB    EF02  BIOS boot partition
   3         1091584       269527039   128.0 GiB   8200  Linux swap
   4       269527040       395356159   60.0 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
   5       395356160       479242239   40.0 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
   6       479242240       500118158   10.0 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
```

and the `/etc/fstab` looks like

```
/dev/sda1               /boot           ext2            noatime 1 2
/dev/sda3               none            swap            sw              0 0
/dev/sda4               /               ext4            noatime         0 1
/dev/sda5               /osgeo          ext4            auto,rw,exec,user 0 2
/dev/sda6               /home           ext4            defaults,noatime 0 2
#/dev/cdrom             /mnt/cdrom      auto            noauto,ro       0 0
```

The /dev/sda1 partition is mounted as reported by `mount`

```
...
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime)
...
```

If it matters, the existing Linux distro has a similar GPT scheme, of course, in another disk than the target for Funtoo. Some info about it:

```
cat /proc/mounts | grep boot
/dev/sdb1 /boot ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdb2 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot ext2 rw,noatime 0 0
```

What else is there to be done? Do I have to mount `/dev/sda2` as well?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: You have to mount both `/` and `/boot` and specify `/boot` as target, so the complete command shall be `grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sda --target /boot`, btw, why two drivers mounted in /boot?

Comment: Thanks @Braiam I answered below... nothing special, really :-/. The partitions in `sdb` are the ones of the current running Linux system. The entry mounting `/dev/sda` was actually inside `/mnt/funtoo/boot`. I did follow closely the installation guide.

Comment: I can't explain why exactly it didn't work "out of the box". I guess it has to do with the fact of `chroot`-ing from another, running, Linux system. I'll wait a bit for comments/ideas if this is of interest. Otherwise, I will (vote to) close this question.

Comment: @Braiam As for the two `boot` partitions, I am not exactly sure... it's openSUSE's guide which I followed (not that closely though, if I remember well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just exited from `chroot`, unmounted all partitions, rebooted (the other Linux distro), and re-did the same stuff (following http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Installation_Troubleshooting). It simply worked!